# C how to find length of struct array

Tags: c

I have a struct array :

```
struct Stu* arr = (struct Stu*)calloc(ogr,sizeof(struct Stu));
```

And I have a void function it gets arr as a paramater and i have to find the len of arr in function.

```
struct Lsn {
    char lsn_name[50];
}; 
struct Stu {
    char name[40];
    char surname[20];
    char st_id[11];
    struct Lsn* lsn;
};
```

Comment: You can't. You must pass the size as a parameter.

Comment: *i have to find the len of arr in function*  You are not going to **find** the length of the array - you have to find a way to **pass** the length in to the function.

Comment: Is it impossible 

Comment: @PaulOgilvie then maybe you could answer by posting an answer

Comment: A pointer is pointing to a single "object" (element) only, nothing more. There's no way to know if that object is the first element of an array-like object, or if it's just the single object, or maybe even a pointer to any *other* element in an array-like object.

Comment: You (your program) created the *array* so you (it) should know.

Comment: but my struct arr is in the struct arr :( i have to print all struct array elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in C to determine the length (size) of an array that is passed as pointer. You must pass the size as a parameter to the function:

```
void f(void *arr, size_t size);
```

If, for one or another reason, that is not possible, and if the array is passed *empty*, then you could do a hack by setting the first bytes of the array to the length, for example:

```
struct Stu* arr = (struct Stu*)calloc(ogr,sizeof(struct Stu));
*((int *)arr)= ogr;
```

and in the function:

```
size= *((int *)arr);   // get the size
*((int *) arr)= 0;     // reset the first few bytes
```

Comment: struct Lsn
{
 char lsn_name[50];
};

struct Stu
{
 char name[40];
 char surname[20];
 char st_id[11];
 struct Lsn* lsn;
}; this is my struct. I have to print all lsn object but i send Stu object to function

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't have a default way to know  the size of array like you want, but you can implement it in the same way a string length is passed down.

In string the character '\0' gives the strin end, so when you calculate the length the function counts the characters till it meets a '\0' character. If memory isn't the problem for you make one extra struct(allocate one extra struct memory). then inside that struct keep something unique so you'll know it denotes the end.  You can then check that value inside the function.

Comment: `calloc` has set everything to zero.

Comment: it doesn't have to be zero. anything works as a flag.

Comment: The problem with any "flag" value used like this to signify the end of an array is that is has to be a value that can never be used by an actual valid value.  That's not that easy to solve.